# How can I paginate products based on specific category laravel-7

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications, laravel-7, web-development-server

I am trying to view retrieve all products in a category and also paginate them into pages.
I am be able to get all products inside any category and it works fine but when I try to paginate them it throws this error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\E-Commerce\resources\views\pages\products.blade.php).

Here is my code.

```
public function show(Category $category, Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::where('id', $request->category->id)->paginate(12);
    
    return view('pages.products')->with([
    'categories' => $categories,
]);
```

And Here is my view.

```
@extends('layouts/default')

@section('title', '| Products')
@section('content')

    @forelse ($categories as $category)
        <h1 class="text-center">{{ $category->name }}</h1>
        <div class="row mt-5 m-5">
            @foreach ($category->products as $product)
                <div class="cols m-4 shadow-lg product product-box"> 
                    <a href="">
                        <h4 class="text-center">{{ $product->name }}</h4>
                        <img class="m-auto" src="{{ asset('images/welcome2.jpg') }}" width="150px">
                        <br>
                        <small class="text-center">{{ $product->details }}</small>
                        <br>
                        <h6 class="float-right mr-1">&dollar; {{ $product->price }}</h6>
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endforeach   
            {{  $category->products->links()  }}
        </div>
    @empty
        <h1>There are no categories yet!</h1>
    @endforelse
    

@endsection
```

Comment: Can you provide the Category class file, so we can see?

Comment: Am having two tables Category, Product with many-to-many relationship and pivot table category_product.

Comment: <?php

namespace App;
use App\Category;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Product;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add paginate on your categories NOT on products.
Please try this code

```
public function show(Category $category, Request $request)
{
    $category = Category::where('id', $request->category->id)->first();
    $products = $category->products()->paginate(15);
     
    return view('pages.products')->with([
    'products' => $products,
    'category' => $category'

]);
```

And in your view

```
@extends('layouts/default')

@section('title', '| Products')
@section('content')

        <h1 class="text-center">{{ $category->name }}</h1>
        <div class="row mt-5 m-5">
            @foreach ($products as $product)
                <div class="cols m-4 shadow-lg product product-box"> 
                    <a href="">
                        <h4 class="text-center">{{ $product->name }}</h4>
                        <img class="m-auto" src="{{ asset('images/welcome2.jpg') }}" width="150px">
                        <br>
                        <small class="text-center">{{ $product->details }}</small>
                        <br>
                        <h6 class="float-right mr-1">&dollar; {{ $product->price }}</h6>
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endforeach   
            {{  $products->links()  }}
        </div>
    

@endsection
```

Comment: I try this it shows another error that paginate doesn't exist

Comment: Oh Sorry , I Fixed now. I add () to products

Comment: `$products = $category->products()->paginate(15);`

Comment: It Works! Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. please accept the answer to other users can find easier the answer to this problem

Answer (score 0):

The right way:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);
        return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

Also you can use simplepagination:

```
$users = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->simplePaginate(15);
```

And the result view:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }}
    @endforeach
</div>
{{ $users->links() }}
```

Comment: I still don't get it, I want to display all products inside a single category and paginate the products.